# $index always 0 when using ng-bind-html

Tags: angularjs

I have a directive that contains this markup

```
<tr ng-if="isComplete()" ng-repeat="row in paged.page() track by $index" ng-click="rowClick(row, $event)" ng-class="assignRowClass(row)">
    <td ng-repeat="header in headers" ng-bind-html="trustAsHtml(header.formatter(row[header.property], row, $index))"></td>
</tr>
```

The problem is that `$index` is always 0 when passed to the header.formatter function.

Comment: can you check trying $parent.$index ?

Comment: yes $parent.$index works which is surprising.  Why is that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As saw in my comment this works

```
$parent.$index
```

This is because of the new scope created by `ng-if` and the limit of inheritance between scope in angular (because of javascript limits).

You can either go for `$parent.$index` of move the ng-if to the upper DOM Element if possible (`<thead>` / `<tbody`).

Answer (score 1):

try this

```
<tr ng-if="isComplete()" ng-repeat="(index,val) in paged.page() track by index" ng-click="rowClick(val, $event)" ng-class="assignRowClass(val)">
<td ng-repeat="header in headers" ng-bind-html="trustAsHtml(header.formatter(val[header.property], val, index))"></td>
```